# Get all possible combinations of quiz answers

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a dictionary with questions as keys and answer option lists as values.

```
quiz = {
  'Question 1': ['yes', 'no'],
  'Question 2': ['dogs', 'cats'],
  'Question 3': ['apples', 'oranges']
}
```

What's the best way to get all the possible answer combinations?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is in fact 8 possiblities `2**3` that you can get with `itertools.product`

```
from itertools import product

quiz = {
    'Question 1': ['yes', 'no'],
    'Question 2': ['dogs', 'cats'],
    'Question 3': ['apples', 'oranges']
}

for responses in product(*quiz.values()):
    print(responses)

# each row is a tuple
('yes', 'dogs', 'apples')
('yes', 'dogs', 'oranges')
('yes', 'cats', 'apples')
('yes', 'cats', 'oranges')
('no', 'dogs', 'apples')
('no', 'dogs', 'oranges')
('no', 'cats', 'apples')
('no', 'cats', 'oranges')
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, I think you meant all *eight* possible combinations for the answers to the three questions. Secondly, since you are enumerating all possible combinations, trying to optimise on the efficiency front is moot - it is going to take exponential time in any case.

Coming to the main question at hand, you can simply iterate through all the items as mentioned in the other answer by azro.

One interesting approach using bit manipulation would go like this:

```
quiz = {
  'Question 1': ['yes', 'no'],
  'Question 2': ['dogs', 'cats'],
  'Question 3': ['apples', 'oranges']
}

for i in range(8):
    ans = [quiz['Question 1'][i & 1], quiz['Question 2'][int((i & 2) / 2)], quiz['Question 3'][int((i & 4) / 4)]]
    print(ans)
```

Explanation: Any combination of answer choices can be seen as taking either the first choice or the second for each question. Forming a corresponding bit sequence leads to a number between 0 to 7 = 2^3 - 1.

NOTE: A major flaw in this method is that this will work only if there are exactly 2 choices for every question. It can be made to work for other variants but it would still require the number of choices to be consistent for each question.